# wamp server crashes after launch phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, registry, wamp

I worked with wamp server for over a month and every thing was great.

Recently I had some chinese viruses that made me take some actions including deleting them from the registry.
When I tried to connect to my wamp server, It turned green, and after I tried to login to the phpMyAdmin, I got an error -

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

This is my Apache error log:

```
[Thu Nov 24 14:06:25.908515 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:25.971016 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:25.971016 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:25.971016 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:26.002265 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6844
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:27.002269 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6844:tid 464] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Thu Nov 24 14:06:27.049144 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6844:tid 464] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:09.243534 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:11.255647 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6844:tid 464] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:11.291651 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2464:tid 576] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6844 exited successfully.
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.192703 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3084:tid 580] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.239706 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3084:tid 580] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.239706 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3084:tid 580] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:43:51
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.239706 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3084:tid 580] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp64\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23'
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.242706 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3084:tid 580] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6848
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.950746 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 6848:tid 408] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
    [Thu Nov 24 14:14:12.992750 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6848:tid 408] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

MySql log:

```
    2016-11-24T12:06:28.111646Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=2525968
2016-11-24T12:06:28.299145Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2016-11-24T12:06:28.783523Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2525968
12:06:59 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=67108864
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 685867 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1ce1d2b1440
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff85d2a42ec    chtbrkg.dll!???
7ff86314b12c    WS2_32.dll!recv()
7ff63e816ef4    mysqld.exe!vio_read()[viosocket.c:123]
7ff63ddaef13    mysqld.exe!net_read_raw_loop()[net_serv.cc:668]
7ff63ddaee61    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet_header()[net_serv.cc:750]
7ff63ddaed55    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet()[net_serv.cc:815]
7ff63ddaf2ae    mysqld.exe!my_net_read()[net_serv.cc:893]
7ff63df49399    mysqld.exe!Protocol_classic::read_packet()[protocol_classic.cc:809]
7ff63de61e68    mysqld.exe!server_mpvio_read_packet()[sql_authentication.cc:1830]
7ff63de60958    mysqld.exe!native_password_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2706]
7ff63de5fe1e    mysqld.exe!do_auth_once()[sql_authentication.cc:1900]
7ff63de5e8ac    mysqld.exe!acl_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2168]
7ff63ddf9e64    mysqld.exe!check_connection()[sql_connect.cc:686]
7ff63ddfa7b1    mysqld.exe!login_connection()[sql_connect.cc:733]
7ff63ddfb086    mysqld.exe!thd_prepare_connection()[sql_connect.cc:877]
7ff63dd9829f    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:294]
7ff63e7c5122    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2191]
7ff63e4db93b    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
7ff63e8873ef    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
7ff63e88763a    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
7ff860e18364    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff8635e5e91    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 2
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
12:14:21 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=67108864
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 685867 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x20e4f1989d0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff85d2a42ec    chtbrkg.dll!???
7ff86314b12c    WS2_32.dll!recv()
7ff63e816ef4    mysqld.exe!vio_read()[viosocket.c:123]
7ff63ddaef13    mysqld.exe!net_read_raw_loop()[net_serv.cc:668]
7ff63ddaee61    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet_header()[net_serv.cc:750]
7ff63ddaed55    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet()[net_serv.cc:815]
7ff63ddaf2ae    mysqld.exe!my_net_read()[net_serv.cc:893]
7ff63df49399    mysqld.exe!Protocol_classic::read_packet()[protocol_classic.cc:809]
7ff63de61e68    mysqld.exe!server_mpvio_read_packet()[sql_authentication.cc:1830]
7ff63de60958    mysqld.exe!native_password_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2706]
7ff63de5fe1e    mysqld.exe!do_auth_once()[sql_authentication.cc:1900]
7ff63de5e8ac    mysqld.exe!acl_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2168]
7ff63ddf9e64    mysqld.exe!check_connection()[sql_connect.cc:686]
7ff63ddfa7b1    mysqld.exe!login_connection()[sql_connect.cc:733]
7ff63ddfb086    mysqld.exe!thd_prepare_connection()[sql_connect.cc:877]
7ff63dd9829f    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:294]
7ff63e7c5122    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2191]
7ff63e4db93b    mysqld.exe!win_thread_start()[my_thread.c:38]
7ff63e8873ef    mysqld.exe!_callthreadstartex()[threadex.c:376]
7ff63e88763a    mysqld.exe!_threadstartex()[threadex.c:354]
7ff860e18364    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
7ff8635e5e91    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): 
Connection ID (thread ID): 2
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
08:18:25 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Attempting to collect some information that could help diagnose the problem.
As this is a crash and something is definitely wrong, the information
collection process might fail.

key_buffer_size=67108864
read_buffer_size=2097152
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 685867 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x2551e8566a0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
7ff85d2a42ec    chtbrkg.dll!???
7ff86314b12c    WS2_32.dll!recv()
7ff7d6046ef4    mysqld.exe!vio_read()[viosocket.c:123]
7ff7d55def13    mysqld.exe!net_read_raw_loop()[net_serv.cc:668]
7ff7d55dee61    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet_header()[net_serv.cc:750]
7ff7d55ded55    mysqld.exe!net_read_packet()[net_serv.cc:815]
7ff7d55df2ae    mysqld.exe!my_net_read()[net_serv.cc:893]
7ff7d5779399    mysqld.exe!Protocol_classic::read_packet()[protocol_classic.cc:809]
7ff7d5691e68    mysqld.exe!server_mpvio_read_packet()[sql_authentication.cc:1830]
7ff7d5690958    mysqld.exe!native_password_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2706]
7ff7d568fe1e    mysqld.exe!do_auth_once()[sql_authentication.cc:1900]
7ff7d568e8ac    mysqld.exe!acl_authenticate()[sql_authentication.cc:2168]
7ff7d5629e64    mysqld.exe!check_connection()[sql_connect.cc:686]
7ff7d562a7b1    mysqld.exe!login_connection()[sql_connect.cc:733]
7ff7d562b086    mysqld.exe!thd_prepare_connection()[sql_connect.cc:877]
7ff7d55c829f    mysqld.exe!handle_connection()[connection_handler_per_thread.cc:294]
7ff7d5ff5122    mysqld.exe!pfs_spawn_thread()[pfs.cc:2191]
```

What can I do?

I tried to reinstall my wamp server.

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the MYSQL log. `wampmanager->MYSQL->Error log`

Comment: @RiggsFolly just add it

Comment: I would guess that the virus has done more damage that you thought or has not been completely removed. I suggest uninstalling WAMPServer, then reinstalling it. Then restoring you database and site from **your last backup**